# CNN: visualize a model using its description

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I created a ResNet model, which I want to show in a presentation, but I don't know how to visualize?
Is there a tool or something to get a graphic from the description of my model.

Here you can see how my description looks (had to cut a part out of it as i were using too many characters):

```
  ResNet(
 (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
 (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
 (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
 (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
 (layer1): Sequential(
   (0): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
     (downsample): Sequential(
       (0): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
       (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
   (1): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (2): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
 (layer2): Sequential(
   (0): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
     (downsample): Sequential(
       (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
       (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
   (1): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (2): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (3): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (4): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (5): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (6): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (7): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
 (layer3): Sequential(
   (0): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
     (downsample): Sequential(
       (0): Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
       (1): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
   (1): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (2): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (3): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (4): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
...

(1): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
   (2): Bottleneck(
     (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
     (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
     (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
 (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
 (fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=2, bias=True)
)
```

I hope someone is able to help me with this.

Comment: I won't answer with a link, but I wanted to do a visualization of my neural network during my training, and a friend gave me this: https://github.com/ashishpatel26/Tools-to-Design-or-Visualize-Architecture-of-Neural-Network . You might want to give it a try.

Comment: that's a good start, thank you

Comment: The `plot_model` function in keras will give you a dot graph representation of your model as a png file, `keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)`

Comment: @Abhi_J nice thank you. is there something like that in pyTorch as well?

Comment: @Bronco95 checkout this module: https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz